# Set theory notation for an array of lists

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

Givan $A$ an array of lists of different length but with the condition that the elements of every list are the same (meaning that if a list in a position $A[i]$ has length $k$ and a list in a position $A[j]$ has length $l$, with $k < l$, the $k$ elements of $A[i]$ are the same as the first $k$ elements of $A[j]$).

How could a I write in a set-theory notation the existence of the longest sublist $p$ in common among every element of the array?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure if I understood the question correctly. Let $A$ be the set of lists as you describe, where we denote a list as $A[i]$ i.e. $A := \{ A[i] \vert i \in I\}$ where $I$ is the index set for this array. Then the longest sublist of those, which is contained in all the lists, would be $\cap_{i \in I} A[i]$.